# NoSuchMessageException with MessageSource in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4 and Spring Data REST. I put my messages.properties inside resources/i18n folder. In this folder I've two files: messages.properties and messages_it.properties
I configured my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter in this way:

```
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        //messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds((int) TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(1));
        messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
        return messageSource;
    }
```

When I have to localize a message I do:

```
        String message = messageSource.getMessage(throwable.getClass().getName(), new Object[] {}, locale);
```

This works fine if the properties file for the language exsists, otherwise I've an exception like:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException' for locale 'fr_CH'.
```

My guess is for some reason MessageSource is not reading the messages.properties file also if it is present and it has the same keys of others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this exception happens when MessageBundle is not configured or configured in wrong way.

change

> messageSource.setBasenames("i18n/messages");

to

> messageSource.setBasenames("/i18n/messages");
>   or messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:/i18n/messages");

if i18n it's root directory for i18n files.

Comment: Thanks you were right. With messageSource.setBasenames("/i18n/messages"); doesn't work but with setBasenames("classpath:/i18n/messages"); it does. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` is different from `ResourceBundleMessageSource`.